# How many semisphere of volume 4l each will be required to tranfer all the water into the small semispheres?

Tags: volume

> A volume of $10936$ l water is in a container of sphere.How many semisphere of volume 4l each will be
>   required to tranfer all the water into the small semispheres?

a)$2812$ b)$8231$ c)$2734$ d)$4222$

**MyApproach**

volume of sphere=$10,936$  L

To divide water into small semisphere,we do=$10,936$/$4$=$2734$

> Can anyone guide me how to approach the problem?

Comment: Your approach looks complete...

Comment: This is not really a geometry problem so tag should be changed.